# React hooks and Material-UI: Snackbar shows once but never again

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

I've isolated my problem here so you can easily reproduce this. **Steps to reproduce:**

**Step 1:** create a react app and add `material-ui` to the project:

```
prompt> create-react-app mui-test
prompt> cd mui-test
prompt> yarn add @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

**Step 2:** change the following files:

**index.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Snackbar } from '@material-ui/core'

interface MessageComponentProps { messages: string[] }

export const MessageComponent: React.FC<MessageComponentProps> = ({ messages }) => {
  console.log("Render MessageComponent... messages: ", messages)
  console.log("messages.length > 0: ", messages.length > 0);

  // This shows the Snackbar once but when I reclick the submit button,
  // it doesn't do it again.
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(true)

  const onClose = () => {
    console.log("calling onClose()...")
    setShowMessage(false)
  }

  if (messages.length === 0) return <></>

  return <>
    <Snackbar
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
      key={`top,center`}
      open={showMessage}

      // eventurally I want to display all messages but this will work for now.
      message={messages[0]}
      onClose={onClose}
    />
    Proof that Snackbar should be rendered here: {messages[0]}
  </>
}

export const PageComponent: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("Render PageComponent...")
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([])

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // simulates a collection of error messages sent back from the server to
    // show to the user.
    setErrors(['Foo ' + Math.random(), 'Bar'])
  }

  return <>
    <MessageComponent messages={errors} />
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} >
      <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained">Submit</Button>
    </form>
    <p>
      What I'm trying to accomplish here is that whenever this button is clicked,
      The snackbar should show and then be cleared when the user clicks away from
      the message. It only does this the first time but doesn't any of the
      consecutive clicks.
    </p>
  </>
}

function App() {
  console.log("Render App...")

  return <PageComponent />
}

export default App
```

**Problem:**
I can get the `SnackBar` message to pop up but when I try to close it, it never does despite the `onClose` method being called. When I try to fix this, it will never actually open (see some of the comments in the code for what I'm trying to do here)

At one point, I could get the `SnackBar` to close. However, hitting the `Submit` button should cause the `SnackBar` message to pop up again but never does after the first time. The only way to get it to come back is if I reload the page and then click the button again.

I'm still pretty new to React so I'm struggling with this but I have a sneaking suspicion that this recipe calls for a `useEffect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your message component use a `useEffect` and listen to `messages`.

```js
const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      setShowMessage(true);
    }
  }, [messages]);
```

In order to close the snackbar you need to either provide an [action](https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/) prop or an `autoHideDuration`

```js
     <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
        key={`top,center`}
        open={showMessage}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        // eventurally I want to display all messages but this will work for now.
        message={messages[0]}
        onClose={onClose}
        action={
          <React.Fragment>
            <IconButton
              size="small"
              aria-label="close"
              color="inherit"
              onClick={onClose}
            >
              X
            </IconButton>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      />
```

Working copy of your [code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-brook-69iih?file=/src/MessageComponent.js)

Comment: This works. Didn't need an `action` or `autoHideDuration` though. I will be using the `Alert` component in Mui's `lab` namespace which does have those options.

Answer (score 0):

There are two quick solutions coming to my mind:

```
{
  Boolean(showMessage) && ----------------Do this
  <Snackbar
  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
  key={`top,center`}
  open={Boolean(showMessage)} --------------- or do this

  // eventurally I want to display all messages but this will work for now.
  message={messages[0]}
  onClose={onClose}
/>}
```

Comment: Or you can share you working code via any 'codesandbox' for detailed solution.

Comment: Check out the other answer. He setup a codesandbox solution. I just needed a `useEffect` hook which is what I was thinking anyway.